# Como exibir validações e erros de domínio numa partial view modal bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou utilizando DDD e tenho algumas validações no meu domínio que precisam ser feitas, porém quando eu utilizo o ModelState.AddModelError e retorno o meu modelo e a minha PartialView, o formulário da minha Partial não permanece no modal aberto. Ao invés disso, exibe uma página html sem estilos css. Sei que tenho que fazer com Javascript/Ajax/jQuery e retornar um Json no Controller. Mas ainda não acertei fazer funcionar. Alguma maneira eficaz de fazer?

Coloquei os códigos para facilitar a visualização de algo que esteja errado. Basicamente o que quero é retornar os erros que acontecerem no controller para serem exibidos dentro da PartialView carregada no modal bootstrap.

Código do Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Adicionar Ação de Formulário";
            return PartialView("~/Views/Acao/_AcaoFormulario.cshtml", _acaoAppService.Iniciar());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Create(AcaoViewModel acaoViewModel)
        {
            JsonResult result;

            var errorResult = new List<ValidationError>();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var acaoReturn = _acaoAppService.Salvar(acaoViewModel, acaoViewModel.AcaoId);

                if (!acaoReturn.ValidationResult.IsValid)
                {

                    foreach (var error in acaoReturn.ValidationResult.Erros)
                    {
                        errorResult.Add(new ValidationError(error.Message));
                    }

                    return result = Json(new ActionResponse(false, errorResult), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }

                return result = Json(new ActionResponse(true, null), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            errorResult.Add(new ValidationError("Ação Inválida"));

            return result = Json(new ActionResponse(false, errorResult));
        }
```

PartialView com Formulário do Carregado no Modal

```
@model PAD.Application.ViewModels.AcaoViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "acaoFrm", onsubmit = "acaoSubmit()" }))
        {
            <div class="card-header">
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="card-title">@ViewBag.Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="card-block">

                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AcaoId)

                    <div class="text-danger">
                        <ul></ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tipo, htmlAttributes: new { @for = "tipo" })
                                @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tipo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@
                                <select class="form-control" id="tipo" name="tipo">
                                    <option>-- Selecionar --</option>
                                    <option value="A">Ação BD</option>
                                    <option value="C">Consulta BD</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FonteDadosId)
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FonteDadosId, Model.ComboFonteDados, "-- Selecionar --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Take)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Take, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Execucao, htmlAttributes: new { @for = "execucao" })
                                @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Execucao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@
                                <select class="form-control" id="execucao" name="execucao">
                                    <option>-- Selecionar --</option>
                                    <option value="E">Excluir</option>
                                    <option value="X">Executar</option>
                                    <option value="S">Salvar</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RotinaId)
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RotinaId, Model.ComboRotinas, "-- Selecionar -- ", new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descricao)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Descricao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PopUpContainer)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PopUpContainer, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Where)
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Where, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "10" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderBy)
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.OrderBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "10" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-danger shadow" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span class="icon-remove"></span> Fechar
                </button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success shadow pull-right" onclick="document.getElementById('acaoFrm').submit();">
                    <span class="icon-check"></span> Salvar
                </button>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript que chama o modal

```
$("#novaAcao").click(function () {
        $("#modal").load("/acao/create", function () {
            $("#modal").modal("show");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o código que você já fez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, vamos por partes:

1. Se sua action é HttpPost, não é necessário o trecho "JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet" (apesar de não ocorrer erro);
2. Seu form já tem o evento "onsubmit" associado. Logo, ao clicar no submit button este evento será disparado automaticamente, sem necessidade deste trecho: onclick="document.getElementById('acaoFrm').submit();
3. Na sua função "acaoSubmit()" chame sua action HttpPost via Ajax. No evento "done()" da chamada Ajax, faça algo do tipo:

```js
.done(function(result){
  if(result.data != null && !result.data.sucesso){ //sucesso: primeiro parâmetro de ActionResponse
    var erros = result.data.errorList; //errorList: segundo parâmetro de ActionResponse
    $.each(erros, function(key, value ) {
      $("#divErros").append("<p>" + value + "</p>"); //crie uma divErros em sua modal.
    });
  }
});
```

4. Seu código fica ainda melhor e mais legível definindo o Response.StatusCode em sua action HttpPost em caso de erro (ex.: 400, 500) ou sucesso (ex.: 200). Neste caso teria que mudar também seu tratamento do retorno da chamada Ajax.
   Aqui vai um exemplo: 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112361/how-to-set-http-status-code-from-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: Valeu mesmo! Era exatamente isso que eu estava procurando. E muito obrigado pelas dicas.